# KDE Plasma autohide panel shows on window focus change

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I have my panel set to autohide, which works almost as expected: It hides when I move the mouse away and shows if I move my mouse to the corresponding screen edge. However, if I change the window focus (ie. by clicking on another window), the panel also shows and only hides again when I move my mouse over it and away again. This only occurs on my PC running Kubuntu 18.04 with KDE Plasma 5.12.9; I have another laptop running OpenSuSE where this works as expected (the panel only shows if I move the mouse over it).

Comment: I have the same issue on Manjaro with Plasma 5.23.5. Two years later this still hasn't been fixed. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @JacobBirkett sadly my only solution until now is to disable autohide...

Answer (score 0):

I found it for us both! The culprit is "Hide utility windows for inactive applications" and I guess this means that unless you're on the desktop, or focusing another Plasma panel, the panel is a "utility window" for its parent.

Here's how to get there:

1. Open **Settings**
2. Open category "**Window Management**"
3. Open category "**Window Behavior**"
4. Open tab "**Advanced**"
5. Uncheck "***Hide utility windows for inactive applications***"

Note that I also changed "*Focus stealing prevention*" in the "Focus" tab. I don't know if this is necessary. I have it on "*Medium*".

It is a shame that this first option is buggy, because it prevents misbehaving programs (KDE Partition Manager) from opening password prompts and such behind. Why? I don't know, that isn't the name of it, but it does that. So there.